# Convert English active voice sentences into passive voice sentences using Machine learning

Tags: machine-learning, python, nlp

Is there any machine learning algorithm developed to convert an English active voice sentence into a passive voice sentence? And what are the datasets available related to that purpose? And also if there are available source codes related to that research idea please mentioned them too.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is various Paraphrasing tool available for Conversion. For datasets, you can search on Kaggle and IEEE Dataport.
I hope you find some of these useful.

Comment: I searched on both Kaggle and IEEE dataport to find a related dataset. But I wasn't able to find one. Do you know any available source code related to that research idea ?

Comment: This might be helpful to you. Kindly check the link 
 https://github.com/DanManN/pass2act